# How do I connect to an AWS MySQL Database using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services

I have setup a new MySQL Database using AWS RDS and am having issues connecting to it, specifically in Python. I have gone through the lengthy process of changing security settings to allow any IP address to connect (just for now while I figure out this issue), connect an EC2 and etc - everything per the guides on AWS. Still unsure where I am going wrong.

Here is my python code below with my database info redacted of course

```
import mysql.connector

db_config = {
    'user': 'db_user',
    'password': 'user_password',
    'host': 'host',
    'database': 'db_name',
    'port': '3306',
    'connection_timeout': 10
}

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)

    if connection.is_connected():
        print("Connected to the MySQL database")


except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print(f"Error: {err}")

finally:
    if 'connection' in locals() and connection.is_connected():
        connection.close()
        print("Connection closed")
```

And here is the specific error Python returns when this code is run (with DB info redacted of course) which I believe may be a timeout error;

`Error: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db_host' (10060)`

Any ideas or help would be excellent, even links to more specific guides than those on AWS would be great

Comment: Hi, there is not enough information in order to give you a straightforward answer. I could give some suggestion you can check anyway:
1. Did you try to connect MySQL instance directly from EC2 console? Is it reachable?
1. 1 If so it means that something wrong with your code. Then make sure you're using correct hostname and port, since the cuse for Timeout errors are usually related to incorrect address you're trying to connect.
1.2 If no, you need to check the following your network settings. I can't give you all possible reasons, since comments are limited with 600 characters.

Comment: Is ec2 instance and the DB is in the same VPC?, and security group of RDS allow the EC2 instance IP range?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to connect to RDS from anywhere, you need to be in the same VPC, its means are you conning from EC2, ECS (container) or Lambda its required to be in the same VPC

When you are inside the same VPC it's required to have a seceurty rule that allow in/outgoing traffic on the right port number as default MySQL runs on 3306.

If this 2 steps are fixed, its a spelling error in your auth settings, :)

late me know if its resolve your problem :)